# Unable to import app.js in other modules in expressJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket

I am Unable to import app.js in other modules in expressJs. It's importing but i am unable to use functions defined in app.js file

Code i have is this-
I have this
app.js

```
var app = express();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(app);
.
.
.
wss= expressWs.getWss();

// console.log(wss);  // works fine
app.getWss=function(){
  return "hello";
  };
app.listen(3001);
module.exports = app;
```

in a file inside /socketroutes/socketroutes.js

```
var app = require('../app');
console.log(app); // prints an empty object {}
console.log(app.getWss())  // returns undefined function and doesn't work
```

I want to use some variables or functions defined in app.js in another modules. because instance of websocket server should be created only once. i cannot create instance of wss in every module.

Comment: Did you get any error?

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly because of a circular dependency.
Try moving the module.exports line to the beginning of the app.js file.